# How to wrap currently selected text in ``

Tags: autohotkey

How can write a hotkey (which works in any editor) to wrap currently selected text in ``

> e.g double click "text", it becomes selected, then by pressing key for single `` it
>   is converted to `text`

Here is mix of pseudo code and actual code. Text within `<>` is what I'm not sure of

```
^<COMMAND FOR PRESSING ` KEY>::
KeyWait Control
<STORE CURRENTLY SELECTED TEXT IN MEMORY>
SendInput `<STORED SELECTED TEXT>'
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is pretty good already. Try this:

```
$`::
clp_tmp := ClipboardAll
send ^c
currently_selected := Clipboard
stringReplace, currently_selected, currently_selected, `r,, All
Clipboard := clp_tmp

sendraw ``%A_Space%
sendraw %currently_selected%
sendraw ``%A_Space%

return
```

`$` is needed because otherwise, ``` sendraw `` ``` would re-trigger this hotkey. The built-in variable [`clipboard / clipboardAll`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm) contains windows' clipboard. Also, you don't need any keywaits. ahk manages concurring modifiers from hotkey triggers by itself. I also suggest using `sendraw` which will **not** treat `#` as the <kbd>win</kbd>-button, `+` as <kbd>Shift</kbd> and so on.

> script inserts new lines between each line if multiple lines are selected

Weird. When using `msgBox, %currently_selected%` instead of any `send` command, the line breaks are displayed correctly... there is obviously some strange formatting going on, I fixed it by simply removing all Carriage Returns (CR) (`` `r ``) from the string which does not change the selected text at all.

The given solution works for my keyboard which is German. *This might be different for other keyboard layouts.* For me, the `%A_Space%` in ``` sendraw ``%A_Space% ``` (at least in the second one) is needed, because if you state ``` sendraw `` ``` (a literal space character in the end), AHK will ignore it. You could also put all three `send`s in one line like

```
sendraw `` %currently_selected%``%A_Space%
```

Another solution might be

`````
sendInput ````{BS}%currently_selected%````{BS}
`````

or just simply

```
sendRaw `%currently_selected%`
```

Finally: If you wanted to make everything easier, make use of the [#EscapeChar](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm) command and change the delimiter from `` ` `` to `\` or sth. similar.

Comment: thanks, but that does not work for me. Behavior is that when press ` after seleting text the text itself is repeated approx 5 times and multiple carriage returns are also sent.  shift + ´ replaces the entire text with `¬

Comment: hell these backticks on stackoverflow drive me crazy, specially in combination with ahk.

Comment: yea I had same issue asking question

Comment: unfortunately I cannot check until tomorrow

Comment: your updated script inserts new lines between each line if multiple lines are selected, but im not sure why as your code looks good?